# Why there are no + and - operators in QTime?

Tags: qt, qtime

I have 2 `QTime`s (intended as time intervals), let's say 1:10:00 and 50:45 (HH:MM:SS).

It seems pretty natural to ask the result of time1 + time2 or time1 - time2.
One has to resort to all sort of very inelegant calls to `addMSecs`, `msecsSinceStartOfDay`, `secsTo` and so on.

Why have they not added simple `operator+` and `-` to `QTime`?

Maybe `QTime` is not a time interval but the time part of a datetime, but then, is there any time interval in QT?

Comment: `setInterval` [bindable] interval : int Note: This property supports QProperty bindings.
This property holds the timeout interval in milliseconds
The default value for this property is 0. A QTimer with a timeout interval of 0 will time out as soon as all the events in the window system's event queue have been processed.
Setting the interval of an active timer changes its timerId().
See also singleShot. 
Qt docs

Comment: @BanAnn What does QTimer::setInterval have to do with this question? QTimer != QTime.